# Can't get my FPS number to show with SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, frame-rate, ostringstream

1. I am making a program that needs to have my FPS counter listed on the top left of the screen. I am using SFML to output my program into a window.
2. I have an FPS.cpp file that contains the class for my FPS counter. There are two methods in this class, "getFPS()" and "update()".

#### fps.cpp

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class FPS
{
public:
   FPS() : mFrame(0), mFps(0) {}


   const unsigned int getFPS() const { return mFps; }
private:
   unsigned int mFrame;
   unsigned int mFps;
   sf::Clock mClock;

public:
   void update()
   {
       if (mClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 1.f)
       {
           mFps = mFrame;
           mFrame = 0;
           mClock.restart();
       }

       ++mFrame;
   }
};
```

#### Game.cpp (SFML inits and Game Loop only)

```
int Game::run()
{
    //Prepare the Window
    window.create(VideoMode(1920, 1080), "GameWindow", Style::Fullscreen);

    FPS fps;
    Text fpsNum;
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("fonts/KOMIKAP_");
    fpsNum.setFont(font);
    fpsNum.setCharacterSize(75);
    fpsNum.setFillColor(Color::Green);
    fpsNum.setPosition(20, 20);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape))
            {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        

        //Update
        fps.update();
        std::cout << fps.getFPS() << std::endl;
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss << fps.getFPS();
        fpsNum.setString(ss.str());

        //Draw
        window.clear();
        
        
        window.draw(fpsNum);
        window.display();
    }

    
    return 0;
}
```

3. When I run `std::cout << fps.getFPS() << std::endl;` the correct FPS is being shown in the console, so I know that getFPS() is doing it's job. From what I understand, the problem lies somewhere in how SFML is displaying the actual text because all I am getting on my screen is a green dot where the FPS should be.

**Picture:**
[Picture of the output, note the green dot at the top left corner.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qab40.png)

**NOTE: I understand that the main function is not shown here, there is no reason for me to show this code as it is not related to the issue.**

**EDIT: I also tried to display a static "Hello" in `fpsNum.setString("hello");` and it did not display that either.**

Comment: why not start with a static "hello" display, if you know the FPS part works?

Comment: are you sure setposition is in pixels and not in screen coordinates (0,0)-(1,1) ?

Comment: the setPosition is in X and Y floats; changing these also works, it just moves the green dot to the new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried to just put a plain text instead of your fps count ? You could try to check if another font would work, or just throw an error if the file does not load.

```
if (!font.loadFromFile("fonts/KOMIKAP_")) {
    std::cout << "Error with the file" << std::endl;
}
```

If you have an error, just try adding a .ttf to the font ?

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue, I forgot to at the .ttf extension in the code!